# What is returned if a select statement returns no rows?

Tags: c#, sql, select

I'm working with SQL now in my programming, and I'm querying a database, like so.

```
scCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT LegislationID FROM Legislation WHERE Number =  @ECERegulation", sconConnection);
        scCommand.Parameters.Add("@ECERegulation", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        scCommand.Parameters["@ECERegulation"].Value = strECERegulation;

        return (int)scCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

My question is, what would be returned if my parameter did not match anything in the table that I am querying?  I need to have an if statement to deal with a non-matching ECERegulation.  Would it return null?  Or would it return the LegislationID of zero?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's stopping you from trying it to find out?

Comment: Or reading MSDN for ExecuteScalar to see if it tells you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty. Returns a maximum of 2033 characters.

Answer (score 2):

If no record is found, it would return `NULL`. So you would get a casting error.

You need to check the result for nullity before casting. And also decided whether to throw an exception or return zero, depending on your business rules.

Comment: Factually wrong.  `DBNull` is returned (especially) if the query returns a single record which holds a database NULL; that's where you get a casting error.  `null` is returned when the query returns 0 records; no casting errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the null by using Nullable< int >. You can also pass the casting error and return null like this.

```
int? GetSomething()
{
     .....
     .....
     return (int?)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(int?)).ConvertFrom(scCommand.ExecuteScalar());
}
```